# How can I wrap Python processes in an OSGi deployment

Tags: python, osgi, apache-felix

I need to integrate a body of Python code into an existing OSGi (Apache Felix) deployment.
I assume, or at least hope, that packages exist to help with this effort.

If it helps, the Python code is still relatively new and small, so can probably re re-architected to meet whatever constraints are needed. However, it must remain in Python, because of dependencies on third-party libraries.

What are suggested best practices?

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to make this an *extender*, see [1](https://www.aqute.biz/2013/11/21/services-vs-extenders.html) and [2](https://v2archive.enroute.osgi.org/doc/218-patterns.html). You want your Python code to be separate from the code that handles the interaction with the interpreter. So what you do is wrap the Python code and any native libraries in a bundle. This is trivial since it is just a zip file.

You then develop a bundle that listens to starting bundle (see the BundleTracker) that have python code. A manifest is often used but you can also look in a directory in the JAR. If you detect this code, you extract any native libraries and run the code in the interpeter of your choice.

If can use JYthon then that would be highly recommended. You can then carry the interpreter as an OSGi bundle that runs on the VM. If you need to use a native compiler your life is less rosy. You can rely on the environment to provide you with an interpreter but then why use OSGi in the first place. You basically lose the write once run anywhere advantage. You could go the full monty by creating bundles that contain Python installers for all platforms you support. Can be done, not even that hard, but a maintenance nightmare. Believe me, native code suck, it only does it a bit faster than Java.